# Existence of a measurable bijection $f:X \to X^2$

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space, where $X$ is an infinite set, and denote by $(X^2,\Sigma^2)$ its product space.

Under which conditions it is true that there exists a *measurable* bijection $f:X \to X^2$?

[I know this a general question and it may not admit an easy answer if it is not "always"; in particular, I am only interested in the case where $X$ is a locally convex topological vector space, and $\Sigma$ stands for its Borel $\sigma$-field]

Comment: I can only say that it is necessary that there exists a bijection between $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^2$.

Comment: If $X \neq \{0\}$ is a separable Banach space,  this is true, since any two uncountable Polish spaces are isomorphic in the category of measurable spaces.

Comment: I agree this answers the question, which has been formulated quite vaguely; but this is much more than required, isn't it?